# Android: Application flow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How does the flow of an Android application go from the readability and re-useability point of view? I created an activity package containing all the activity required for my application, a dbAdapter package where all the queries related stuffs are present and a model containing getters and setters.

How do I create a manager/service package and interact with the dbAdapter? This is is a part of my dbAdapter:

```
public DbAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.helper=new DbHelper(this.context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public DbAdapter open(){
    database=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Creating the table and inserting some data on initialization
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        //Upgrade code goes here

    }
}
```

I use this code for the initialization in some Java class of activity package:

```
dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
dbAdapter.open();
```

If I want to do the same from a manager package having a Java file, then what do I pass for the context argument of `DBAdapter` constructor which contains a parameter?

How will the flow go in an Android application?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my project described in Stack Overflow question *[Unable to collect data from a .db file of SQLite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923063/cant-able-to-collect-data-from-a-db-file-of-sqlite-in-android)* with some prior modification. You will be able to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. I am not able to import this properly into my eclipse workspace. Can you please specify if this is a project interchange file or not? Please inform how to import it into eclipse.